# How to eliminate old content with jQuery Without using Empty() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a crossword project and I am almost there.. But I am facing a problem..

in my HTML code I have a selective list that I use to load the .JSON file using Javascript.

```
        <form method="post" id="formulaire">
        <div class="toto">
            <select id="myselect" name="grille">
                <option selected="selected">Choisir</option>
                <option value="test1.json">test1</option>
                <option value="test2.json">test2</option>
            </select>
</form>
```

And in my Script file, I have declared the functions and at the end I use

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myselect').on('change', function (e) {
            init($('#myselect').val()); /* This is a declared function already to draw the grid and the other things I wanna do and it works well.*/

        });

     });
}) (jQuery);
```

So now when I select for example `test1` from the list, the grid is loaded well and everything is okay. But when I select `test2`, the page gets corrupted and I get the 2 grids inside each others and everything gets worse.

I want to find a way to do what I wanna do properly without any problem. Which means when I re-select another grid, it appears and the old one is not there anymore.

I tried to use `empty()` function after the `init(..)` call, but it clears all the page and there is nothing at all at the page whether with the first select of the second..

Any ideas?

**the init() fonction

```
function init(link) {

    $.getJSON(link, function (data) {
        //set up the crossword
        var puzzle = data.solution;
        var cheat = 0;
        $div = $('#container');
        $("#author").append('<b>' + data.author + '</b>');

        var start = Date.now();// for calculating the time purpose
       // Creating the list of clues
        for (i = 0; i < data.acrossClues.length; i++) {
            if (data.acrossClues[i] != null) {
                $(".listhorizontal").append('<li id="selects">' + data.acrossClues[i] + '</li>');
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < data.downClues.length; i++) {
            if (data.downClues[i] != null) {
                $(".listvertical").append('<li id="selects">' + data.downClues[i] + '</li>');
            }
        }
        // creating the grid 
        for (var i = 0; i < data.nRows; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.nCols; j++) {
                var $block = $('<div class="block" data="false" select="false" wordselect="false" cheat="false"><div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div></div>');
                if (j == 0) $block.css('clear', 'both');
                $div.append($block);
            }
        }


        for (var row = 0; row < puzzle.length; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < puzzle[row].length; col++) {
                if (puzzle[row][col] != ".") {
                    addLetter(puzzle[row].charAt(col), row + 1, col + 1, 0);
                }
            }
        }
./* + many functions for event handling.. */
    });
};
```

Comment: Please add the code for the `init()` function. We are not able to help you without the code that manipulates the HTML. And on which selector did you use the `empty()` on?

Comment: empty() clears the entire html of the selector on which it is called. Its very difficult to comment on without knowing the structure of your grid and how you are interpreting the data from our JSON. It would help if you could provide a snippet of your JSON and may be the structure of your HTML

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf I tried it but still the same problem..

Comment: @JohannesJander I used the empty() on the div that contains the grid and the lists of clues created

Comment: Found it. thanks guys for your help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **.empty()** or you could use **.html()**, but the key is to call those methods on the HTML element that needs to be cleared out. If you call it on an element that is too high up in the DOM structure, you will wipe out too much content.  Find the element that is the closest wrapper to the content you need erased and use empty() or html() on that element.

It looks like `$div` is the container object, so call `empty()` or `html()` on that.

**Do this just BEFORE the init call, not AFTER** because calling it after will wipe out whatever init just created.

Comment: That worked. I used to select the whole <div> that contains the grid and the lists.

now I selected the <div> for the grid and the two <divs> for the 2 lists generated and it worked :)

Comment: But it seems like the page is still corrupted eventho everything looks clear..
The first Grid is okay and I can fill it without any problem.
But when I select another grid, the old grid disappears and everything looks okay, but the filling is not okay at all. You think think is going to take alot of handle? Because my project is due tonight and I still have other necessary functions and duties to do.. @ScottMarcus

Comment: It's tough to say without you posting all your code (all the HTML as well as the JS)

Comment: That's going to be hard because of the length of the code :/

I don't know if there is a method to send the code directly to someone or not

Comment: We don't want you to send code directly to individuals, but you can create a JSFiddle or embed a code snippet in your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5kev232u/ 
@ScottMarcus  It might seem ambiguous, try to copy the javascript I have into a JS file and link it. Same goes with CSS and try to understand what I wanna do. Thank you Note: I think the jQuery is not linked
This is for one of the JSONs file https://jsfiddle.net/g7t98zdL/ ( you can save it in a JSON file, name is as shown in the selective list.. )